# How were the Welsh Triads used by the Welsh?

Tags: welsh-triads

There have been a few questions about the [meaning of various welsh triads on this site](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welsh-triads). However, I'm curious about how these triads were used by the Welsh. Were the triads similar to a collection of proverbs that would be referenced in daily life? Or were they, [as wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_Triads), solely used as a mnemonic device to remember longer versions of stories?

Just to clarify: it's less that I don't trust wikipedia (although I have a hard time believing that the triads were *solely* used as a mnemonic device), and more that I would like an answer that goes into a little bit more detail (the wikipedia only had one sentence about this topic).